# Converting binary into categorical

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the form of

```
     black  orange   yellow    green
  1    0      1         0        1
  2    0      0         0        1
  3    1      0         0        0
```

I would like to create another column that would tell which colours are present, so the final output SHOULD be:

```
     black  orange   yellow    green  colours
  1    0      1         0        1    orange and green
  2    0      0         0        1       green 
  3    1      0         0        0       black
```

Thanks in advance.
P.S. Forgot to add there are a lot more columns than this - plenty of more colours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with the columns names and then remove last `5` values:

```
df['colours'] = df.astype(bool).dot(df.columns.astype(str) + ' and ').str[:-5] 
print (df)
   black  orange  yellow  green           colours
1      0       1       0      1  orange and green
2      0       0       0      1             green
3      1       0       0      0             black
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `apply`:

```
>>> df['colours'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' and '.join(x[x == 1].index), axis=1)
>>> df
   black  orange  yellow  green           colours
1      0       1       0      1  orange and green
2      0       0       0      1             green
3      1       0       0      0             black
>>>
```

Comment: Doesnt work due to this error: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Otherwise the code looks great

Comment: @FafamKurac123 Then use: `df['colours'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' and '.join(x[x == 1].index.astype(str)), axis=1)`